# What does |> (pipe greater than) mean in R?

Tags: r, pipe, operators, r-faq

I have recently come across the code `|>` in R. It is a vertical line character (pipe) followed by a greater than symbol.

Here is an example:

```
mtcars |> head()
```

What is the `|>` code doing?

Answer (score 65):

`|>` is the base R "pipe" operator. It was [new in version 4.1.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html).

In brief, the pipe operator provides the result of the left hand side (LHS) of the operator as the ***first*** argument of the right hand side (RHS).

Consider the following:

```
1:3 |> sum()
#[1] 6
```

Here, the vector of numbers 1 through 3 is provided as the first argument of the `sum` function.

The left hand side result always becomes the first argument of the right hand side *call*. Consider:

```
args(sum)
#function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 

c(1:3, NA_real_) |> sum(na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 6
```

The emphasis on *call* is important because you can redirect the LHS to other arguments as long as the first argument is **named**. Consider:

```
args(rnorm)
#function (n, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
100 |> rnorm(n = 5)
#[1]  99.94718  99.93527  97.46838  97.38352 100.56502

args(sum)
#function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 
sum(na.rm = TRUE, ... = c(1:2,NA_real_))
#[1] 3
TRUE |> sum(... = c(1:2,NA_real_))
#[1] NA
```

---

One benefit of using the `|>` operator is that it can make code more easy to follow logically compared to nested function calls:

```
split(x = iris[-5], f = iris$Species) |>
  lapply(min) |>
  do.call(what = rbind) 
#           [,1]
#setosa      0.1
#versicolor  1.0
#virginica   1.4

#Compared to:
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(iris[-5],iris$Species),min))
```

---

This functionality is similar to the [`magrittr::%>%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) operator (also implemented in `dplyr`).

However, unlike `%>%`, there is no current way to pipe the LHS into the right hand side multiple times or into arbitrary positions. Magrittr uses the `.` placeholder for the LHS and `{}` to place it arbitrarily.

```
library(magrittr)
iris[iris$Sepal.Length > 7,] %>% subset(.$Species=="virginica")

TRUE %>% {sum(c(1:2,NA_real_),na.rm = .)}
[1] 3
```

Additionally, unlike the base R `|>`, the `%>%` operator can pipe into function calls without `()`:

```
1:3 |> sum
#Error: The pipe operator requires a function call as RHS

1:3 %>% sum
#[1] 6
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that this throws an error: `1:3 |> sum` whereas this does not `1:3 %>% sum`.

Comment: You could use anonymous function `TRUE |> {\(x) sum(c(1:2,NA_real_), na.rm = x)}()#
[1] 3`

Comment: @akrun I was actually thinking of doing a `\()` Q&A too, but maybe you want to?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck not without the parentheses.

Comment: Obviously. That was the point I was making.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that `1:3 |> sum()` is parsed as `sum(1:3)`, this is a big difference with {magrittr}

Comment: R 4.2 introduced the placeholder `_` to put the LHS into any named RHS parameter, albeit only once. For a lack of a better example, this works: `'world' |> gsub(pattern='there', replace=_, 'hello there')`, but this doesn't: `'world' |> gsub(pattern=_, replace=_, 'hello there')`. I imagine this will be worked on in future R releases.

Answer (score 15):

To see how the piped code gets parsed we may use `quote()`.

*Examples:*

```
quote(1:3 |> sum())
# sum(1:3)

quote(100 |> rnorm(n = 5))
# rnorm(100, n = 5)

quote(split(x = iris[-5], f = iris$Species) |>
        lapply(min) |>
        do.call(what = rbind))
# do.call(lapply(split(x = iris[-5], f = iris$Species), min), what = rbind)
```

Answer (score 12):

Since I also recently stumbled upon this pipe in a peer's code I looked into the topic and found out that **as of R 4.2** you can also pipe the LHS into the right-hand side at arbitrary positions (however, not multiple times, only once) and with a different syntax:

As of R 4.2: you can use `|>` in combination with `_`

This means, base R can do some of what magittr does, too:

```
# magittr
library(magrittr)
TRUE %>% sum(c(1:2, NA_real_), na.rm = .)

# R 4.2 onwards
TRUE |> sum(c(1:2, NA_real_), na.rm = _)
```

As of R 4.1 you can use `=>` in combination with a variable that you pipe into `|> a => f(..., x = a, ...)`

```
# R 4.1 onwards
# you have to set the '_R_USE_PIPEBIND_' envvar to a true value to enable =>
Sys.setenv("_R_USE_PIPEBIND_"=TRUE)
TRUE |> a => sum(c(1:2, NA_real_), na.rm = a)
```

Comment: `TRUE |> {sum(c(1:2,NA_real_),na.rm = _)}`
Error: function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe

Comment: @DongdongKong I cared for it, I think the curly braces were overkill.