# How to install Hmisc.r package

Tags: r, package

I try to install the Hmisc package, but get the following error:

> Error in parse(outFile) :
> C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpkByp0H/R.INSTALL3f9c251b32c4/Hmisc/R/movStats.r:398:43:
> unexpected '>' 397:             else 398:               info <-
> knitr::kable(info) |>
> ^ ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'Hmisc'

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Comment: What version of R are you using? Are you sure it's compatible with the version of Hmisc you're using? From that error message, I think you're using a [pre-4.1.0 version of R that doesn't have the base pipe operator (`|>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67744604/8366499). If not, either update R or look on CRAN to find the version of Hmisc that is compatible with the R version you're using and [download that specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17082341/8366499)

Comment: It looks like this has been reported as an issue: https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/issues/159. The package description file does not declare the necessary minimum R version.