# How to calculate the percentages of total patients in a pivot_wider dataframe?

Tags: r, group-by, pivot

For a medical dataset I need to summarize the SAEs, and display the amount of occurrences per group of patients. The patients all belong to a randomisation group, but not all patients have SAEs and some patients can have more than 1 of the same.

I am able to get the absolute numbers, but is there a way to (also) get the percentages?

Here is the code I've got so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_patients <- read.table(text = "
patid,rnd_group,DoB,Sex
8961,1,24-03-1972,M
1977,1,12-04-1979,M
6193,2,12-10-1984,M
6752,1,09-01-1975,F
7842,1,27-03-1980,M
4403,3,27-07-2003,F
1479,2,31-08-1990,M
9056,3,13-01-2005,M
3929,2,07-02-1997,F
3371,3,05-02-1997,M
9667,2,16-10-2008,M
9777,2,27-07-2000,F
4171,2,06-01-1983,F
6207,1,11-07-1987,F
6375,3,04-05-1988,F
", header = TRUE, sep = ",") #  

df_sae <- read.table(text = "
patid,code,txt
1977,10028810,Common cold
6193,10028810,Common cold
9056,10012735,Diarrhea
9777,10028810,Common cold
6193,10011224,Cough
4171,10028810,Common cold
6193,10028810,Common cold
4171,10012735,Diarrhea
3929,10011224,Cough
6207,10028810,Common cold
", header = TRUE, sep = ",") #  

# Merge the dataframes based on patient_id and visit_date
df_merged <- merge(df_sae, df_patients, by = c("patid"))

df_pivot <- df_merged %>%
  group_by(code, txt, rnd_group) %>%
  arrange(rnd_group, txt) %>%
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(patid)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rnd_group, values_from = Count, names_prefix = "Group")
```

The output is like below, which is correct but it is the absolute count of patients

| code | txt | Group2 | Group3 | Group1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10011224 | Cough | 2 | NA | NA |
| 10012735 | Diarrhea | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 10028810 | Common cold | 3 | NA | 2 |

I've tried changing the code like below, but that only results in the percentages of the SAE counts not the percentage of patients per total group.

```
df_pivot2 <- df_merged %>%
  group_by(code, txt, rnd_group) %>%
  arrange(rnd_group, txt) %>%
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(patid)) %>%
  mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count) * 100) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rnd_group, values_from = c(Count, Percent), names_prefix = "Group")
```

There are 5, 6 and 4 patients in Group1, Group2 and Group3. So the desired result would be like this, either combined or as separate columns, whatever is easiest.

| code | txt | Group2 | Group3 | Group1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10011224 | Cough | 2 (33.3%) | NA | NA |
| 10012735 | Diarrhea | 1 (16.7%) | 1 (25.0%) | NA |
| 10028810 | Common cold | 3 (50.0%) | NA | 2 (40.0%) |

Is there a way to this either with dplyr, or some other way?

Comment: Why are there 5, 6 and 4 patients in Group1, Group2 and Group3? Isn't it 2, 6 and 1?

Comment: No, that's just the patients with SAEs. In the total group of `df_patients` there are 15 patients, it's just that not all of them have SAEs, which is also representative of the real dataset.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```
df_sae |>
  left_join(select(df_patients, patid, rnd_group)) |>
  summarize(count = n_distinct(patid), 
            .by = c(code, txt, rnd_group)) |>
  left_join(summarize(df_patients, group_size = n_distinct(patid), .by = rnd_group)) |>
  mutate(pct = count / group_size * 100, 
         values = stringr::str_glue("{count} ({pct})")) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(code, txt),
              values_from = values, 
              names_from = rnd_group,
              names_prefix = "Group")
```

**Output**

```
      code txt         Group1 Group2               Group3
     <int> <chr>       <glue> <glue>               <glue>
1 10028810 Common cold 2 (40) 3 (50)               NA    
2 10012735 Diarrhea    NA     1 (16.6666666666667) 1 (25)
3 10011224 Cough       NA     2 (33.3333333333333) NA
```

---

If you intend on performing additional calculations I would advise against putting your counts and percentages into a single string. Additional computations are also generally easier to code and run faster in long format and should be done (if possible) before your pivot, FYI.

```
df_merged %>%
  group_by(code, txt, rnd_group) %>%
  arrange(rnd_group, txt) %>%
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(patid)) %>%
  group_by(rnd_group) %>%
  mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count) * 100,
         values = stringr::str_glue("{Count} ({Percent})")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(code, txt),
              names_from = rnd_group, 
              values_from = values, 
              names_prefix = "Group")
```

Before your `mutate` statement you need to group by `rnd_group` to get group percentages. Otherwise, you are still grouped by `code` and `txt` from your earlier `group_by`. `summarise` throws the following warning to make you aware of this:

> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'code', 'txt'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

I added a column `values` used in the pivot that pastes `Count` and `Percent` into one string. The other thing you are missing is `id_cols`. If this is not specified then all the columns not listed in `names_from` and `values_from` become the `id_cols`, which is not what you want.

---

**Output**

You can use any number of functions like `scales::percent_format` or `formatC` to format your percentages either when you create `Percent` or you can use them directly in the `str_glue` function. You may also consider `names_sort = T` in your pivot statement to order your columns how you might expect:

```
      code txt         Group2               Group3  Group1 
     <int> <chr>       <glue>               <glue>  <glue> 
1 10011224 Cough       2 (33.3333333333333) NA      NA     
2 10012735 Diarrhea    1 (16.6666666666667) 1 (100) NA     
3 10028810 Common cold 3 (50)               NA      2 (100)
```

Comment: Ok but this doesn't take into account the fact that the actual patient groups are larger, i.e. there are patients that do not have any SAEs and the percentages are different from the example result. I think the total group counts needs to be added at some point, not sure at which step or what would be the best way to use it though.

Comment: @BdR see update. From what I can tell there are 5 patients in group 1 so it should be 2/5 = 0.4.

Comment: Thanks, the updated code is exactly what I was looking for. The main clues are using `left_join` instead of `merge` to join the dataframes, and to use the `left_join(summarize(df_patients..` to get the group totals. Btw I assume the pipes `%>%` and `|>` are interchangable?

Comment: you're right, my bad, it should be 40% not 20% for `Group1`, I've just updated it in the original question.

Comment: Quick follow up question, when I change values to `values = stringr::str_glue("{pct:0.2}%"))` to get rounded percentages, I get the weird error `values must be size 1555 or 1, not 4.` any idea how to get just 2 decimals?

Comment: The magrittr pipe `%>%` and the base R pipe `|>` are similar but also have some distinct differences you should be aware of. I think long term the base R pipe will take over. Read this post for [more information about the base pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744604/what-does-pipe-greater-than-mean-in-r). To format your output try `{format(round(pct, 2), nsmall = 2)}`.